# Can't add items to ListView from my XMLs in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, linq

The main problem is this one.

I have 2 XMLs containing information about what my company does. One is considered the template XML where you can find the general information and the other one  is the Catalog containing information about each individual equipment, containing a reference to the template XML.

They look like this
Catalog XML

```
<list>
   <A>
      <B>
        <c>reference to template</c>
        <d>info 2</d>
        <e>info 3</e>
        <f>info 4</f>
        <g>
            <h>info5</h>
            <i>info5</i>
        </g>
      </B>
      <B>
        <c>reference to template</c>
        <d>info a</d>
        <e>info s</e>
        <f>info d</f>
        <g>
            <h>infof</h>
            <i>infog</i>
        </g>
      </B>
      <B>
        <c>reference to template</c>
        <d>info h</d>
        <e>info j</e>
        <f>info k</f>
        <g>
            <h>infot</h>
            <i>infoy</i>
        </g>
      </B>
   </A>
</list>
```

Template

```
<list>
   <R>
      <S>
        <t>info 7</t>
        <u>info 8</u>
        <v>info 9</v>
        <w>info 10</w>
      </S>
   </R>
</list>
```

What I need to do is to display all of the equipment catalogued in a listView, which will lits information from both XMLs.

I've tried that and had no succes, all I can display is one equipment, weel it actually isn'y displayed, all that appears is invisible information. 
I run through both XMLs using this:

```
xDocument load = xDocument.load("Myxml.xml");
var run = (from x in load.Descendants("A")
           where x.Element("c").Value == comboBox1.SelectedItems.ToString()
           select new
           {
             a = x.Element("d").Valuye.ToString(),
             //here I gather the rest of the information
           }).ToList();
listView.Items.Add(run);
//after that I tried listview.Items.Add(run.a) ... but the code which I use to run through
//ends with FirstorDefault(), instead of ToList() and I try adding all the components manually
```

The only thing that Appears is an invisible Equipment, which means that when I click on it I can see there's something there, but I just can't see the information.

So I tried adding strings using the same methodology, but got the same result.

Can anyone please tell me where's my mistake? I can't see it.

PS: After I manage to do this, I'm gonna Implement a function, that by double clicking on the information, the client will be able to alter the information. If someone knows where to start with this one, please point me in the right direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what was wrong, I needed to add an observable collection, to which I added the content I wanted to put on the viewlist, and then I put the information in the observablecollection in the viewlist.

**Thank you all for helping me.**

Answer (score 1):

I believe your linq query needs a bit of a touch up, something like:

```
xDocument load = xDocument.load("Myxml.xml");
var run = (from x in load.Descendants("B")
       where x.Element("c") == comboBox1.SelectedItems.ToString()
       select new
       {
         a = x.Element("d").Valuye.ToString(),
         //here I gather the rest of the information
       }).ToList();
```

Also, you should try using a for loop on the list and adding the strings one by one

```
foreach (var item in run)
    listView.Items.Add(item.a);
```

You can take a look at the different overloads of the Add method on this MSDN page:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.listviewitemcollection.aspx

Comment: I've already tried that and wasn't successful. All I get is the "invisible" content as I called it earlier

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I'm not entirely sure what the question is. I'll take a shot at the `XDocument` query, though.

When doing comparisons, you need to compare the correct types. The comparison from the example won't even compile because there is a comparison of an `XElement` with a `String`:

```
where x.Element("c") == comboBox1.SelectedItems.ToString()
```

Should be:

```
where x.Element("c").Value == comboBox1.SelectedItems.ToString()
```

If the overall goal is to get a list of strings from the query, then take a look at the following:

```
string match = comboBox1.SelectedItems.ToString();

var doc = XDocument.Load( "MyXml.xml" );

var query = doc.Descendants( "B" )
    .Where( x => x.Element( "c" ).Value == match )
    .Select( x => x.Element( "d" ).Value )
    .ToList();
```

Notice that the query starts with the "B" element. Starting at the "A" element will result in 0 elements matched in the where clause.

Also, it is easier to break these types of problems down by using additional variables to break down the statement, i.e., variables for the matching criteria, for the XDocument, for the query, etc... Even the query could be broken down into further sub-queries if needed.

This should get you started.

Comment: Sorry, I typed the wrong code here, but on the real program I did it the right way. And also, I tried adding values manually, not from XML, but data I just made up on the spot. I tried copying exmples for adding items but they just didn't work

Comment: You need to post real code examples that expose the problem you are having difficulty solving. Try re-wording your question with actual code from your problem. It'll be easier if you just stick to one question at a time as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the `Detail` mode of the list view, you need to add `columns` to the list and `subitems` in the items corresponding to each column, else your items will be "invisible".

See the `ListView.Columns` and `ListViewItem.SubItems` members for more details.

Comment: I already added the columns with listview, and whenevfer I create a listvieitem I just don't get the subitems method or attributre, it simply says that it's not available for listviewitem